# Discord presence using interactions.py

Tags: python, discord

So I have a basic bot created with one command so far but I can't seem to figure out how to make it change Rich Pressence.

```
import interactions

bot = interactions.Client(token="XYZ")

@bot.event
async def on_start():
    await bot.change_presence(interactions.ClientPresence(activities=[interactions.PresenceActivity(name=f"Testing", type=interactions.PresenceActivityType.WATCHING)]))

@bot.command(
    name="testing",
    description="TEST.",
    scope=XYZ,
)
#async def COMMAND NAME
async def testing(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    await ctx.send("**This is a response to testing command**"

bot.start()
```

The bot runs and listens to commands but it doesn't update its RP. I am still learning Python so perhaps this is too big of a project to take on :(

I have gone through several webpages with details or code examples but were unable to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not fully answering the question, but I managed to make it work using the [`pypresence`](https://pypi.org/project/pypresence/) library.

You can use this code:

```py
from pypresence import Presence
from time import time
RPC = Presence('Your application ID')
RPC.connect()
RPC.update(state='Your description here', start=time(), instance=True, large_image='your image name')
```

You first import the modules, then create a `Presence` object. The ID you will need to use is available on [discord.dev](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[image]

On discord.dev, under <kbd>Rich Presence</kbd> > <kbd>Art Assets</kbd>, you can add an image that you will be able to display by referencing its name using `RPC.update` like in the last line in the code.

More info here: https://qwertyquerty.github.io/pypresence/html/doc/presence.html

---

#### EDIT:

If you want your bot to have a custom Discord Presence, make sure to create another application in discord.dev, the one from which the application ID will be used by your bot program to *play* using `pypresence`.

---

Be careful, you will (of course) need to have Discord installed in order to use the `pypresence` module.

Comment: Hey there! I have just read that RPC can't be used with bots but clients only :( Sorry for the hassle, will try to figure something else out!

Comment: @TastyCZ maybe you could create another application and make your bot use `pypresence`. In this case, you would have say your "Bot" application and a "Game" application, and you bot will need to connect to "Game" with `pypresence` to show your "Bot" playing "Game" in Discord.

Comment: Thats what I did indeed! Works great!